# How to check the number of KDF rounds of a Ed25519 SSH key?

Tags: ssh

Ed25519 SSH keys can be generated with a specific number of KDF rounds with the following command:

`ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -a 21` (default is 16)

Given the files `id_ed25519` and `id_ed25519.pub`, how to find this number of rounds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that this is a property of the private *key file*, not of the private key. It's used to derive the key encryption key from the passphrase (as a parameter of a [password-based key derivation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching)). You can change the number of rounds when changing the passphrase with `ssh-keygen -p`.

There doesn't appear to be a way to find this property with `ssh-keygen`. `ssh-keygen -l -v` only shows properties of the key and some associated metadata, not including how the key is encrypted.

The private key file format is partially documented in [`PROTOCOL.key`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/PROTOCOL.key). My answer is based on this, on source reading and on experimental observation.

The OpenSSH native format of private keys consists in Base64-encoded data wrapped between two lines `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----` and `-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----`. `PROTOCOL.key` describes the content of the Base64-encoded binary data. The binary data is a sequence of fields of the following types:

- `byte[]`: a string of bytes whose length is known in advance.
- `string`: a string of bytes whose length is encoded before the string as a 4-byte big-endian number.
- `uint32` or `int`: a 4-byte number encoded big-endian.

The binary data contains the following fields:

- The literal string `openssh-key-v1␀` where `␀` s a null byte (`byte[]`)
- cipher name (e.g. `aes256-ctr`) (`string`)
- PBKDF name (as of OpenSSH 8.1: `bcrypt` or `none`) (`string`)
- PBKDF options (`string`)
- (and we don't care about the rest)

The PBKDF options are themselves structured as a sequence of fields. For `bcrypt`, they are:

- salt (`string`)
- number of rounds (`uint32`)

Here's how to inspect a private key file visually to find the KDF information.

```
$ <id_ed25519 grep -v '^-' | base64 -d | xxd -g1
00000000: 6f 70 65 6e 73 73 68 2d 6b 65 79 2d 76 31 00 00  openssh-key-v1..
00000010: 00 00 0a 61 65 73 32 35 36 2d 63 74 72 00 00 00  ...aes256-ctr...
00000020: 06 62 63 72 79 70 74 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 10 fe  .bcrypt.........
00000030: 57 c1 fe c6 47 cf 63 34 ef 83 35 61 aa f6 31 00  W...G.c4..5a..1.
00000040: 00 00 15 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 33 00 00 00 0b 73  ..........3....s
00000050: 73 68 2d 65 64 32 35 35 31 39 00 00 00 20 7b c8  sh-ed25519... {.
…
```

From the beginning, follow the three human-readable strings (`openssh-key-v1`, `aes256-ctr`, `bcrypt`. After that, there's a compound string with the PBKDF options consisting of 24 bytes preceded by `00 00 00 18`. Those 24 bytes consist of:

- The salt length (`00 00 00 10`).
- The salt (16 bytes as indicated by the salt length).
- The number of rounds (`00 00 00 15`) — that's 0x15 = 21.

If you want to extract this programmatically, rather than write your own script, there's a Python library for that: [`openssh-key-parser`](https://pypi.org/project/openssh-key-parser/).

```
$ pip install -U openssh-key-parser
…
$ python3 -m openssh_key id_ed25519 | jq '.header.kdf'
Key passphrase: 
"bcrypt"
$ python3 -m openssh_key id_ed25519 | jq '.kdf_options.data.rounds'
Key passphrase: 
21
```

Comment: Thanks. With this Python tool I also discovered the comment (parameter `-C` of `ssh-keygen`) is not only a string added at the end of the public key, but also stored in the private key (encrypted).

Comment: for all, like me the kdf_options.rounds return in null, try use .kdf_options.data.rounds